# Can I use gunicorn when deploying a django app on Windows?

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying to deploy a django app with Heroku and am getting caught up on my Procfile. The tutorial I am going off of uses gunicorn but I've read that I cant use gunicorn because I am developing on Windows.
My Procfile looks like:

```
web: gunicorn my_site.wsgi --log-file -
```

and I am recieving this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_site'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Gunicorn built with unix I/O multiplexing mechanism(epoll/kqueue). If you want to develop your program in Windows. I recommend you use WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't more documentation on this. I am following some tutorials on youtube and they mention nothing about needing to develop on Linux in order to deploy.

Comment: @johnrogeksu If you want deploy a WSGI application(Django/Flask) to Windows. You needn't develop it in Linux. The problem is Gunicorn is not a application for Windows. It can't be run in Windows. You need to find a WSGI server that can be run in Windows. Even if you follow the tutorial in MSDN, they use WSL